# Количество одинаковых строк в столбце

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

К примеру, у меня есть таблица звонков с полями "номер телефона" и "статус":

```
date       | phone       | status
2017-01-02   84990000000   'BUSY'
2017-01-04   84990000000   'FAIL'
2017-01-05   84990000000   'OK'
2017-01-02   84990000001   'OK'
2017-01-10   84990000001   'FAIL'
2017-01-13   84990000001   'OK'
2017-01-15   84990000001   'FAIL'
```

Мне нужно для каждого номера вывести количество `BUSY`, `FAIL`, `OK` в отдельных столбцах, т.е. должно получиться:

```
phone       | count_busy | count_fail | count_ok
84990000000   1            1            1
84990000001   0            2            2
```

Написал вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT
   phone,
   COUNT(call_status = 'BUSY') as busy_count,
   COUNT(call_status = 'FAIL') as fail_count,
   COUNT(call_status = 'OK') as fail_count
FROM calls
GROUP BY phone
```

Но результат запроса неправильный, похоже, что `COUNT(call_status = 'строка')` работает вообще не так, как я предполагаю.

Где тут косяк?

Comment: Любой логический оператор в MySQL возвращает 0 или 1. А count() считает все NOT NULL значения. ни 1 ни 0 не является NULL. Используйте `sum()` она отлично посчитает единицы

Comment: `Select Field1, count(*) from Table WHERE 'your_field=blablabla' group by Field1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   phone,
   sum(case when call_status = 'BUSY' then 1 else 0 end) as busy_count,
   sum(case when call_status = 'FAIL' then 1 else 0 end) as fail_count,
   sum(case when call_status = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end) as fail_count
FROM calls
GROUP BY phone
```

Comment: можно обойтись без `case when`.